# Efficient thumbnail creation in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiimage, thumbnails

What's the most efficient way to create a thumbnail from an arbitrary web image in iPhone?

Comment: ImageIO is still the fastest as of 2014.  For a good summary of additional techniques, refer to this article: http://nshipster.com/image-resizing/

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The only way that I've found so far that works on any images is to show it in an ImageView with the right size, and then create a bitmap from that view.

Far from efficient, though.

Comment: With respect to the author, this should not be marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 8):

the comparison of two method for fast creating thumbnail from image
kindly see this link for detail 
http://www.cocoaintheshell.com/2011/01/uiimage-scaling-imageio/
or 
http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/

for future , just copy pasting code from first one

**First method, using UIKit**

```
void)buildGallery
{
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < kMaxPictures; i++)
    {
        NSInteger imgTag = i + 1;
        NYXPictureView* v = [[NYXPictureView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){.origin.x = x, .origin.y = y, .size = _thumbSize}];
        NSString* imgPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", imgTag] ofType:@"jpg"];
        UIImage* fullImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imgPath];
        [v setImage:[fullImage imageScaledToFitSize:_thumbSize]];
        [fullImage release];
}
```

Results of the benches gave me the following :

- Time Profiler : 4233ms
- Live bytes : 695Kb
- Overall bytes used : 78.96Mb

**Second method, using ImageIO**

```
-(void)buildGallery
{
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < kMaxPictures; i++)
    {
        NSInteger imgTag = i + 1;
        NYXPictureView* v = [[NYXPictureView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){.origin.x = x, .origin.y = y, .size = _thumbSize}];
        NSString* imgPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", imgTag] ofType:@"jpg"];
        CGImageSourceRef src = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:imgPath], NULL);
        CFDictionaryRef options = (CFDictionaryRef)[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:(id)kCFBooleanTrue, (id)kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailWithTransform, (id)kCFBooleanTrue, (id)kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageIfAbsent, (id)[NSNumber numberWithDouble:_maxSize], (id)kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize, nil];
        CGImageRef thumbnail = CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex(src, 0, options); // Create scaled image
        CFRelease(options);
        CFRelease(src);
        UIImage* img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:thumbnail];
        [v setImage:img];
        [img release];
        CGImageRelease(thumbnail);
    }
```

he benches gave me this :

- Time Profiler : 3433ms
- Live bytes : 681Kb
- Overall bytes used : 77.63Mb

**You can see that using ImageIO is about 19% faster than UIKit, and also uses slightly less memory**.

Answer (score 2):

[This is best way that I've found.](http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/)

Comment: Gave me "CGBitmapContextCreate: unsupported colorspace." on first try. After checking the comments it seems that the scope of that library is very limited. I can't assume much of the images (other than they are PNG or JPEG).

Comment: That is caused by the API being very fussy about the relationship between the bit resolution, the alpha and the colorspace. You have to check that the image has the correct configuration and then create a new, properly formatted image if it does not. That is really unavoidable. I don't think anyone has done a generic resize that works with everything.

Comment: How do I check if it has the right configuration and then create a properly formatted image if it does not?