# ios7 app terminated due to memory pressure in UItableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

i have `uitableview` with customer `UitableViewcell` my cell hold in the `Uiimageview` 
i use the `Url` to load image to my `UIimageView` so in the scroling in the tableview my app crashing
my code source :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   ActusCell  *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
       NSDictionary *tmpDict = [_MyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    dispatch_async ( dispatch_get_global_queue (DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0ul),  ^{
        act_Image=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.exemple.com/act/%@%@",[tmpDict objectForKey:@"id"],@".jpeg"];
        NSURL * imageURL =  [ NSURL URLWithString :act_Image ];
        NSData  * imageDataUrl =  [ NSData dataWithContentsOfURL : imageURL ];


                dispatch_async ( dispatch_get_main_queue (),  ^ {
                [cell.myimage setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageDataUrl]];

       });
    });
    return cell;
}
```

N.B :the image in the URl have size 1.2MB

Comment: Why you throw the whole 1.2 MB image into your tableViewCell? I think you should optimize the size of the image file. How about trying a small size image like 10 kb and see if it will crash?

Comment: @Ricky with small size my app not crash the problem with the big size :s

Comment: @Ricky how to optimize the size of the image file have you some aide ?

Comment: Ideally scale the remote images to the correct side (if something under your control). Otherwise: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13629828/404201

Answer (score 1):

I think You should load image asynchronously and save that in cache.For that there is so  many third party source available. I found this are the best of them-

1.https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView
2.https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by your dispatches. They're never cancelled.
You should look into starting to use `NSOperation` and `NSOperationQueue` when the cell is being reused, cancel the operation it was performing.